# mviewer/OpenLayers: Create proportional circles from the centroids of each polygon in a layer

Tags: polygon, openlayers, point, centroids, mviewer

I have created a mviewer map. This one is based on OpenLayers 7.1.

I created a map from a point layer added as WFS from my GeoServer. This layer shows the population using proportional circles.
The larger the population, the larger the circle.

Here is the code that works:

```
{
  mviewer.customLayers.city = {};
  var city = mviewer.customLayers.city;

  mviewer.customLayers.city.layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: url,
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: function (feature) {
      var fill = new ol.style.Fill({ color: 'rgba(235, 179, 185, 0.21)' });
      var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({ color: 'rgba(200,86,86)', width: 2 });

      if (feature.get('p19_pop') <= 1000) {

        return new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 5,
            fill: fill,
            stroke: stroke
          })

        });
      }
      else if (feature.get('p19_pop') > 1000 && feature.get('p19_pop') <= 2000) {

        return new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 10,
            fill: fill,
            stroke: stroke
          })

        });
      }
      else if (feature.get('p19_pop') > 2000 && feature.get('p19_pop') <= 3000) {

        return new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 15,
            fill: fill,
            stroke: stroke
          })

        });
      }
      else if (feature.get('p19_pop') > 3000 && feature.get('p19_pop') <= 4000) {

        return new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 20,
            fill: fill,
            stroke: stroke
          })

        });
      }
      else if (feature.get('p19_pop') > 4000 ){

        return new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 25,
            fill: fill,
            stroke: stroke
          })

        });
      };


    }
  });

  mviewer.customLayers.city.handle = false;
}
```

I would like to do the same thing for a polygon layer by taking the centroid of each polygon in the layer.
I have tried several times using the above code or using patterns but nothing comes close to the desired result.

How to modify the above code so that it works for a vector polygon layer?

Answer (score 1):

`image` styles only work with Point geometry, if you wish to show an icon or other image in a Polygon or LineString you must specify a point geometry.  OpenLayers has an interior point which it uses for text labels

```
   new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        fill: fill,
        stroke: stroke
      }),
      geometry: feature.getGeometry().getInteriorPoint()
    });
```

To calculate a centroid see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/modify-scale-and-rotate.html

Comment: For getting polygon centroid [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/docs/#centroid) library `.centroid` method could be used.